# How to revoke refresh token in Identityserver4?

Tags: identityserver4

I need to revoke the refresh token by user and client. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Can I use the [revoke endpoint](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/revocation.html) for refresh tokens?

Or do I need to write code. I am using EF in Identity, in startup I have:

```
AddOperationalStore(options => ....)
```

There seems to be two options to delete tokens:

- IPersistentGrantStore:RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)
- IRefreshTokenStore:RemoveRefreshTokensAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)

Which one can I use for this purpose?

Or should I implement the code for the delete as described in [this article](https://mcguirev10.com/2018/01/02/identityserver4-without-entity-framework.html)?

Comment: It's a very long article, try to be more specific. You may want to include the part of code you think is relevant (from the article).

Comment: Ok maybe that question is not relevant.
I want to delete refresh token by subjectId and clientId.
Which method do I implement and how do I call it?

Comment: IRefreshTokenStore:RemoveRefreshTokensAsync calls IPersistentGrantStore:RemoveAllAsync, but I recommend using the IRefreshTokenStore you have registered to make the call since it's at a higher level of abstraction

Answer (score 1):

If you need to revoke all the tokens for a given SubjectId/ClientId combination, you cannot use the revoke endpoint you list in your question. That's intended to revoke a **single** token.

The article you link is about not using ASP.NET Core Identity. That is a different matter and should have no impact on your desire to remove all refresh tokens for a user.

The way to go is indeed use the `IRefreshTokenStore.RemoveRefreshTokensAsync` method, where you can provide the SubjectId and ClientId. This does not necesarely 'revoke' the tokens, it removes them all from the database.